# Show with delay directive

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and have made my first directive. Is this a good or a bad way to do this?  It works, but can't figure out if this is clever or not.

```
.directive('showWithDelay', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
            $element.addClass("ng-hide");
            $timeout(function() {
                $element.removeClass("ng-hide");
            },attrs.showWithDelay);
        }
    }
})
```

Usage in template

```
<a class="button button-block rounded" show-with-delay="6000">CLICK ME</a>
```

button will be displayed after 6 sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me, I would add some small changes:

If you create a directive/service/controller/.. in Angular it's a best practice to create them with the `[ ]` notation to make sure minifying your code won't break:

```
.directive('name', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) { 

} ] );
```

In your example a minifier would change the $timeout variable to something as `'a'` which will result in an error because `'a'` is not registered and thereby not known by Angular's dependency injection system.

In my example if a minifier would change $timeout it doesn't matter at all since a minifier doesn't change string values. A rule of thumb, always [ngminify](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) your code before jsminify.

And as last I would add a default value for the timeout function:

```
 $timeout(function () {
     $element.removeClass("ng-hide");
 }, attrs.showWithDelay || 5000);
```

This way if someone does not provide an attribute it will take the default value of 5000.